# How to get div from foreach with jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery

I'd like to create a show more/less function for every filters to hide their related options by default and only show the one's options which has been clicked.

The problem is that when I click on any "show more" button every filter's options show up and not the current which has been clicked and vica versa.

I'm showing the filters and their options by looping through with foreach, and I don't know how to get with jQuery a curtain one.

I guess all the divs which was created by looping should have a unique identifier what I've tried with *id = "{{ $filter->id }}"*

Thank you for all of your help!

```
@foreach($filters as $filter)

<h4>{{ $filter->title }}</h4>
<a class="readmorebtn">Show options</a><br> 

    <div class="options" id ="{{ $filter->id }}">

    @foreach($filter->filteroptions as $option)
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="filteroptions[]" value="{{ $option->id }}" />
                {{ $option->title }}
            </label>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>

@endforeach
```

And this is the jQuery part :

```
var moreText = "Show options",
    lessText = "Hide options",
    moreButton = $(".readmorebtn");


$(".options").hide();

moreButton.click(function () {

    $this = $(this);

    if($('div.options:hidden')) {
        showDiv();
    }

    $this.text($this.text() == moreText ? lessText : moreText);
});


function showDiv() {

    $('div.options').slideToggle("fast");

}
```

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle for the same , http://jsfiddle.net . instead of php script use  the html generated from it in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your accessing all the `divs` and toggling them when `more` button  is clicked.

**How it should be:**

- Pass the current object and fetch the current `div.options` and then perform the operation to toggle the effect.

**JS CODE:**

```
var moreText = "Show options",
lessText = "Hide options",
moreButton = $(".readmorebtn");

$(".options").hide();

moreButton.click(function () {
  $this = $(this);

  // if current div is hidden, then toggle it
  if($this.find('div.options:hidden')) {
    showDiv($this);
  }

  $this.text($this.text() == moreText ? lessText : moreText);
});


function showDiv($currentDiv) {
 $currentDiv.find('div.options').slideToggle("fast");
}
```

Comment: well if you can create a jsfiddle, i can check it there . concept wise its correct but just need to check for some syntactical error.